# Append() function working in chrome but NOT in firefox, Hierarchy error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so I have form information on a modal, and I need to close the modal (But not submit the form) and then open up another modal and then once they hit the submit button on THAT modal, it makes an AJAX call to a PHP file, with the old form.

I am doing this by taking the form information and moving the whole element to a `hidden_div`, and then I just append the info onto a form when I am ready.

Works on Chrome, doesn't work on Firefox.

```
switch_form_event = button.closest('.create-event-form');
hiddenDiv = $('#hidden_inner_div');
parent = switch_form_event.closest('.reveal');
hiddenDiv.attr("name", parent.id.toString());
switch_form_event.style.display = "none";
$(hiddenDiv).append($(switch_form_event)); //FAILS HERE
```

I have tried other things like: `hiddenDiv += switch_form_event` but that doesn't work.

The error I get is:

> Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy

The node should just be form info without the form tags, aka: `<input value='123'/>` etc.

Comment: It's really hard to figure this out without also seeing the related HTML

Comment: What type of element is `switch_form_event`?

Comment: Barmar, switch_form_event is just a regular <div>

```
 <input type="hidden" name="user" value="' . $USER->id . '"/>
      <!--Removed PIN input, as it is recorded elsewhere and is not the default value of $USER->pin anymore.-->
      <input type="hidden" name="drill" value="0" />
      <input type="hidden" name="type" value="' .
        $planEventType['emergency_type_id'] . '" />
      <input type="hidden" name="lat" value="" />
      <input type="hidden" name="lng" value="" />
      
```

Comment: You don't need to move anything around unless the first modal is destroyed. If it's just hidden then it should remain in the DOM. When you collect the final piece of information in the second modal, you can do an ajax post to the php page using the data from both modals. You don't actually need the form element, unless you're using some form validation plugin.

Comment: Maybe you can just use $(hiddenDiv).append(switch_form_event);  It looks like maybe that is already a jQuery object.

Comment: That's how I originally had it =/

Answer (score 0):

Both `hiddenDiv` and `switch_form_event` are already JQuery objects. Also, `style` is not a property of a jQuery object. It may be that your error is actually being caused by something else that you don't realize.

Try this:

```
switch_form_event = button.closest('.create-event-form');
hiddenDiv = $('#hidden_inner_div');
parent = switch_form_event.closest('.reveal');
hiddenDiv.attr("name", parent.id.toString());
switch_form_event.css("display", "none");
hiddenDiv.append(switch_form_event);
```

If that still doesn't work, please post the relevant HTML code.